# Is it my jQuery code or Internet Explorer that is wrong?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following code to load an external page into a "holder" div on my main site. It works fine in Firefox but when a user views it in Internet Explorer 7 it seems to hang for a minute or two and then starts to work normally. Also when someone resizes the browser window the site seems to hang again. Is there something wrong with the code below or is it just the limitations of jquery/javascript in Internet Explorer? The basket.cfm loads content from a database and the loadMyBasket function is called when a user clicks a link on a different part of the site.

```
$.loadMyBasket = function () {
    $('.menuHolder').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $('.menuHolder').load('http://www.mysite.com/includes/basket.cfm?selectedDay=6-Mar-11', function () {
            $('.menuHolder').fadeIn('fast')
        })
    });
};
```

The code above gets loaded automatically when the site first loads and also gets called when the user clicks a link to update the basket.

Comment: What happens if you call some other URL, say a static one?

Comment: There is no words in any language that can accurately describe my hatred for IE.

Comment: How much HTML is actually inserted into `.menuHolder`?  IE7 is notoriously awful for DOM manipulation.

Comment: What happens when you replace the fade functions with show and hide?

Comment: I have found jQuery has quite a few "unexpected features" when viewing in IE7 mode - and in IE8 with the dreaded compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with your code, this may be just an IE issue. Make sure you update your version of jQuery to the most recent. Also, I would experiment with fadeOut speeds.

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically Internet Explorer is always wrong, so it could be both.  You are missing a `;` as well.

[Lots of problems reported in IE6/7 with jQuery if you Google it.](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=jquery%20ie7%20fadein)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the HTML from the external page is having issues with IE7 and is causing it to hang.

It would be worthwhile checking with another static page with controlled HTML elements to make sure it is the jQuery code that is causing IE7 to hang.

Comment: I've been doing a bit more investigating and it seems that the culprit may not be .load. I am using the quickFlip plugin on content from a database and when I disable that the page seems to load and resize the way it is supposed to. so it solves one problem but now I need to work out why quickFlip is slowing down the site. Sorry to waste everybodys time about jquery and IE but if you have any thoughts on quickFlip I would like to hear them!